# Actionscript 3 jumping animation issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation

> Im having this issue where when I press the up key for my player to jump, the player goes to the jump animation but immediately returns to the idle animation while in mid air. My question is how can i get the player to hold the jump animation and then return to idle once he reaches the ground.

```
import KeyObject;
import flash.events.Event;

var hsp = 15; 
var vy:Number = 0;//Vertical speed variable
var grav:Number = 20;//gravity variable
var jumped:Boolean = false;//Checking if we jumped, false means 
//not jumping

warMage.gotoAndStop("idleWarmage");
//Player initially starts with idle animation

var Key:KeyObject = new KeyObject(stage);//Adds the new method for keyboard check

//The stage always checks for these events and functions
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameloop);

function onEnter(e:Event):void
{   

    if(Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT))//Check if right arrow is pressed
    {
        warMage.x += 15;//Move at this speed
        warMage.gotoAndStop("RunWarmage");//Play this animation
        warMage.scaleX = 1;//Keep the image svale to right
    } 
    else if(Key.isDown(Key.LEFT))//Check if left arrow is pressed
    {
        warMage.x -= 15;//Move left
        warMage.scaleX = -1;//Flip the image
        warMage.gotoAndStop("RunWarmage");//Play this animation
    }
    else if(Key.isDown(Key.UP))//Check if spacebar is pressed
    {
        if(!jumped)//the boolean is true
        {
            vy -= 70;//Player jumps 50 pixels upward
            jumped = true;
            warMage.gotoAndStop("JumpWarmage");//Play the jump animation
        }
    }
    else
    {
        warMage.gotoAndStop("idleWarmage");//Return to idle state
    }
}
function gameloop(e:Event):void
{
    if(warMage.x + 36.55 < 0)//Setting room boundaries
    {
        warMage.x = 0;//Setting boundary on right
    }
    if(warMage.x + 55.22 > 999)//Setting boundary on left
    {
        warMage.x = 999;
    }
    vy += grav;
    if(!ground.hitTestPoint(warMage.x + 36.55, warMage.y + 55.22, true))//If we're not on a surface
    {
        warMage.y += vy;//apply gravity to the player   
    }
    for(var i = 0;i < 109; i++)
    {   //If the warmage is on the ground
        if(ground.hitTestPoint(warMage.x + 36.55, warMage.y + 55.22, true))
        {
            warMage.y--;//A pixel above the platform
            vy = 0;//Gravity isn't applied on the player
            jumped = false;//We're not jumping
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as per the code you posted as soon you key up, it will go to "idleWarmage",

Comment: Is there a specifc command that can say hold the animation until the player reaches the ground?

Comment: There are no readymade command. Warmage can only go to idle if jumped is false. And when jump animation complete you should make that jumped variable false.

Answer (score 0):

You said this was AS3, but `Key.isDown()` is a deprecated AS2 class.function

In any case, you've declared that `onEnter` would run on every frame (just as your `gameloop` does), therefore unless you are holding down the directional arrows, or are currently releasing the spacebar, then it will predictably run `else { warMage.gotoAndStop("idleWarmage"); }`.

1. I've replaced your AS2 methods with AS3 Keyboard events (meaning the logic only fires when you're actually interacting with the keyboard).
2. Your `jumped` boolean is confusing as appears to refer to what **was** rather than what **is**; even your comments clarified it in the present tense of "jumping", so I've done the same.
3. The true goal of your conditionals is to see whether your character should be idle or not.  This is determined by whether they're currently not moving or jumping.  Since we can articulate this during each keypress, the `idle` boolean can be set concisely.
4. Finally, with only one `enterFrame` function firing, moving the character is now handled the same way your gravity was, with `warMage.x += vx;`

See the revised code below.  Hope it helps.  =)

```
import flash.events.Event;

var hsp = 15; // the horizontal speed of the character
var vx:Number = 0; // Horizontal speed variable
var vy:Number = 0; // Vertical speed variable
var grav:Number = 20; //gravity variable
var jumping:Boolean = false; // False means we're not jumping.
var idle:Boolean = false; // Whether or not the character is idle

warMage.gotoAndStop("idleWarmage"); //Player initially starts with idle animation

//The stage always checks for these events and functions
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyEvents);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyEvents);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameloop);

function keyEvents(e:KeyboardEvent) {
    if (e.type == KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 39: // Right Arrow
                vx = hsp; //Move at this speed
                warMage.gotoAndStop("RunWarmage"); //Play this animation
                warMage.scaleX = 1; //Keep the image svale to right
                idle = false;
                break;
            case 37: // Left Arrow
                vx = -hsp; //Move left
                warMage.scaleX = -1; //Flip the image
                warMage.gotoAndStop("RunWarmage"); //Play this animation
                idle = false;
                break;
            default:
                if (!jumping) {
                    idle = true;
                }

        }
    }

    if (e.type == KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 39: // Right Arrow
            case 37: // Left Arrow
                vx = 0;
                if (!jumping) {
                    idle = true;
                }
                break;
            case 32: // Spacebar
            case 38: // Up Arrow
                vy -= 70; //Player jumps 50 pixels upward
                jumping = true;
                idle = false;
                warMage.gotoAndStop("JumpWarmage"); //Play the jump animation
                break;
        }
    }

    if (idle) {
        warMage.gotoAndStop("idleWarmage"); //Return to idle state
    }
}

function gameloop(e:Event):void {
    warMage.x += vx;

    if (warMage.x + 36.55 < 0) { //Setting room boundaries
        warMage.x = 0; //Setting boundary on right
    }

    if (warMage.x + 55.22 > 999) { //Setting boundary on left
        warMage.x = 999;
    }

    vy += grav;
    if (!ground.hitTestPoint(warMage.x + 36.55, warMage.y + 55.22, true)) { //If we're not on a surface
        warMage.y += vy; //apply gravity to the player   
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 109; i++) { //If the warmage is on the ground
        if (ground.hitTestPoint(warMage.x + 36.55, warMage.y + 55.22, true)) {
            warMage.y--; //A pixel above the platform
            vy = 0; //Gravity isn't applied on the player
            jumping = false; //We're not jumping
        }
    }
}
```